# cmake: linking against STATIC IMPORTED library fails

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a vendor provided static library.

I have added it as a `STATIC IMPORTED` library target, and set properties on the target:

```
add_library(
    lime_api 
        STATIC 
        IMPORTED
    )

set_target_properties(
    lime_api 
        PROPERTIES 
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/trading/limeTradingApi.a"
    )

# users include "api/trading/limeTradingApi.h"
set_target_properties(
    lime_api 
        PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/.."
    )
```

elsewhere in my source tree I try to link against `lime_api`, and I get an error:

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llime_api
> ```

My source tree looks like this:

```
src
|
+--- api
|    | 
|    +--- trading
|    |       - limeTradingApi.a
|    |       - limeTradingApi.h
|    |
|    +--- examples
|         |
|         +--- trading
|
+--- order
     |
     +--- example
```

The strange thing is that there is a vendor provided example which links against this library, and that works fine:

**`api/examples/trading/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
add_executable       (trading_demo exampleClient.cc)
target_link_libraries(trading_demo lime_api)           <-- this works
```

However, when I try linking against my own library which includes the `lime_api` I get the linker error.

**`order/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
add_library(
        order
            STATIC
            ${SRCS}
        )
target_link_libraries(order lime_api)                  <-- this doesn't work
```

**`order/example/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
add_executable       (order_example main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(order_example order)
```

### Question:

Why doesn't CMake *"convert"* the linked target `lime_api` into `-llimeTradingApi.a` for my executable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you ran into a visibility problem with the `IMPORTED` library target. According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html):

```
An IMPORTED library target references a library file located outside the
project. ... The target name has scope in the directory in which it is
created and below, but the GLOBAL option extends visibility.
```

That's why the correct library path is used for the inner `trading_demo` target, but not for the outer `order_example` target. To fix the problem, adding the `GLOBAL` option should be sufficient:

```
add_library(lime_api STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
```

Comment: Gah! I missed `GLOBAL` in the docs! I wish I could upvote you more! Thank you!